# Detailed Proof of Knowledge for Discrete Log

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm, schnorr-signature

I'm having difficulty finding a detailed proof for one of the most basic protocols in cryptography, that is the Schnorr protocol, or the sigma protocol for proving knowledge of a discrete log.

Most proofs I can find gloss over the running time of the extractor, or just assume the prover works with probability 1. But the prover could succeed with any probability $\epsilon > 1/2^\lambda$ and the extractor must operate in expected time $poly(\lambda)/(\epsilon-1/2^\lambda)$. Furthermore, the extractor has no control over the prover except what challenges it feeds to the prover (e.g. the prover's randomness is independent of the extractor). These criteria come from what I understand to be the commonly accepted definition of 'proof of knowledge' from [On Defining Proofs of Knowledge](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48071-4_28).

Where can I find an acceptable proof that abides by these criteria?